# GSA dynamic navigation -- Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration, google-search-appliance

The GSA(Google Search Appliance) provides dynamic navigation links illustrated in the image below [image: dynamic navigation links]

I am using the clustering api to get the json response of the search results but it doen't provide me the navigation links. Is there anyway to get these.

Please Help. Thanks in Advance.

**EDIT**

[Here is a link to the GSA docs](http://code.google.com/apis/searchappliance/documentation/610/)

Comment: What do you mean by "clustering api" ?  Is it the "Narrow Your Search" functionality? I suppose both Dynamic Navigation and Clustering doesn't work simultaneously.